# Access Array in PHP with uncommon var name in it

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays, json

I'm using PHP Laravel Framework, so at the time of generating a SQL query, I calculate the average of some score like this

$average = ... SELECT AVG(score) FROM ... (tables)

And works perfect!

But at the time of printing the variable $average I see in the browser the following array or JSON:

```
[
  {
     "avg(score)": 8.952380952381
  }
]
```

So I don't know how to save this number in a variable. 
Earlier I did  $variable->id to reach its value, but now I cannot call 
"$average->avg(score)" due to the parenthesis.

I know it's a basic question, but I'm mixed up by different languages, so I wanted to solve this quick. I don't find this concrete example on the Net.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just name/alias the field returned in the resultset from the datbase, like this:

```
SELECT AVG(score) AS average FROM ...
```

Comment: In case you wanna know how to access an object field with special chars in it in PHP: `$variable->{'AVG(score)'}`

Comment: Aw-some! =D It worked, and saved lot of time wandering lost on Google.
Thanks a lot!! =)))